Sympy nsolve returns lambdify TypeErrors
I am trying to solve an overdefined system of equations nummerically with Sympy nsolve, but I keep getting lambdify TypeErrors.
import sympy as sp

f25 = 61900.
f50 = 66200.
f75 = 70700.
f90 = 77700.

#mu = sp.Symbol('mu')
#sigma = sp.Symbol('sigma')

mu = sp.var('mu')
sigma = sp.var('sigma')

def f(x):
    f = (1 / sp.sqrt(2 * sp.pi * sp.Pow(sigma,2))) * sp.euler(-1 * (sp.Pow(x - mu,2)) / (2 * sp.Pow(sigma,2)))
    return f

f1 = f(f25) - 0.25
f2 = f(f50) - 0.50
f3 = f(f75) - 0.75
f4 = f(f90) - 0.90

sp.nsolve((f1, f2, f3, f4), (mu, sigma), (66000, 10000))

returns
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mpmath\calculus\optimization.py:937, in findroot(ctx, f, x0, solver, tol, verbose, verify, **kwargs)
    936 try:
--> 937     fx = f(*x0)
    938     multidimensional = isinstance(fx, (list, tuple, ctx.matrix))

File <lambdifygenerated-5>:2, in _lambdifygenerated(mu, sigma)
      1 def _lambdifygenerated(mu, sigma):
----> 2     return ImmutableDenseMatrix([[mpf((1, 1, -2, 1)) + (mpf(1)/mpf(2))*sqrt(2)*euler(-mpf((0, 239475625, 3, 28))*(1 - mpf((0, 2384070316472963, -67, 52))*mu)**2/sigma**2)/(sqrt(pi)*sqrt(sigma**2))], [mpf((1, 1, -1, 1)) + (mpf(1)/mpf(2))*sqrt(2)*euler(-mpf((0, 68475625, 5, 27))*(1 - mpf((0, 139325861583909, -63, 47))*mu)**2/sigma**2)/(sqrt(pi)*sqrt(sigma**2))], [mpf((1, 3, -2, 2)) + (mpf(1)/mpf(2))*sqrt(2)*euler(-mpf((0, 312405625, 3, 29))*(1 - mpf((0, 8349304248355101, -69, 53))*mu)**2/sigma**2)/(sqrt(pi)*sqrt(sigma**2))], [mpf((1, 8106479329266893, -53, 53)) + (mpf(1)/mpf(2))*sqrt(2)*euler(-mpf((0, 377330625, 3, 29))*(1 - mpf((0, 3798557338215609, -68, 52))*mu)**2/sigma**2)/(sqrt(pi)*sqrt(sigma**2))]])

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mpmath\ctx_mp_python.py:346, in _constant.__call__(self, prec, dps, rounding)
    345 if dps: prec = dps_to_prec(dps)
--> 346 return self.context.make_mpf(self.func(prec, rounding))

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mpmath\libmp\libelefun.py:116, in def_mpf_constant.<locals>.f(prec, rnd)
    115 wp = prec + 20
--> 116 v = fixed(wp)
    117 if rnd in (round_up, round_ceiling):

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mpmath\libmp\libelefun.py:97, in constant_memo.<locals>.g(prec, **kwargs)
     96 if prec <= memo_prec:
---> 97     return f.memo_val >> (memo_prec-prec)
     98 newprec = int(prec*1.05+10)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for >>: 'int' and 'mpf'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 24
     21 f3 = f(f75) - 0.75
     22 f4 = f(f90) - 0.90
---> 24 sp.nsolve((f1, f2, f3, f4), (mu, sigma), (66000, 10000))

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\utilities\decorator.py:88, in conserve_mpmath_dps.<locals>.func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     86 dps = mpmath.mp.dps
     87 try:
---> 88     return func(*args, **kwargs)
     89 finally:
     90     mpmath.mp.dps = dps

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\solvers.py:3000, in nsolve(dict, *args, **kwargs)
   2998 J = lambdify(fargs, J, modules)
   2999 # solve the system numerically
-> 3000 x = findroot(f, x0, J=J, **kwargs)
   3001 if as_dict:
   3002     return [dict(zip(fargs, [sympify(xi) for xi in x]))]

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mpmath\calculus\optimization.py:940, in findroot(ctx, f, x0, solver, tol, verbose, verify, **kwargs)
    938     multidimensional = isinstance(fx, (list, tuple, ctx.matrix))
    939 except TypeError:
--> 940     fx = f(x0[0])
    941     multidimensional = False
    942 if 'multidimensional' in kwargs:

TypeError: _lambdifygenerated() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sigma'

I have tried to define my variables as both sp.Symbol and sp.var.
I have tried to bracket the variables to solve for: sp.nsolve((f1, f2, f3, f4), [(mu, sigma)], (66000, 10000)). But that just gives me a new TypeError: TypeError: nsolve expected exactly 1 guess vectors, got 2
Bracketing my input guess values yields yet another TypeError: sp.nsolve((f1, f2, f3, f4), [(mu, sigma)], [(66000, 10000)]). TypeError: cannot create mpf from (66000, 10000).
As I am sure you can tell I have all but given up, and are going at it brute force "monkeys and typewriters" style.
Can anyone offer up any advice?

Looking at your f(x), they appear to be some kind of normal statistical distribution. If so, you might want to replace sp.euler with sp.E ** , where sp.E is Euler's number.

True, it is the binomial distribution. And your excellent suggestion solved the TypeError conondrum. Now I just need to provide better starting guesses — but that is a problem for another time. ;-) Thanks!

Looking at your f(x), they appear to be some kind of normal statistical distribution. If so, you might want to replace sp.euler with sp.E ** , where sp.E is Euler's number.

True, it is the binomial distribution. And your excellent suggestion solved the TypeError conondrum. Now I just need to provide better starting guesses — but that is a problem for another time. ;-) Thanks!
